# video controls in adobe edge

Tags: video, adobe, controls, adobe-edge

Im hoping somebody could help me here - I'm not a programmer, I'm a graphic designer who has started putting together a showreel in Adobe Edge Animate. It's all going well until I embed a video into nested symbols using the following code:

```
var vid = sym.$("Holder");
vid.html('<video id="myVideo" width = "1232" height = "692" src = "video/myVideo.mp4" type = "video/mp4" controls = "controls"> </video>');
```

The problem I'm having is that the video controls don't work allowing me to play or pause. This code works when the video holder is at stage level, but not when it's nested in symbols. My only alternative is to replace controls = "controls" with autoplay loop. But I would really like the controls to be available!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!